# Identifying source of FALSE

Tags: r

My question is, does there exist a function that, given a logical statement, identifies the source of FALSE (if it is false)?

For example,

```
x=1; y=1; z=1;
x==1 & y==1 & z==2
```

Obviously it is the value of `z` that makes the statement false. In general though, is there a function that let's me identify the variable(s) in a logical statement who's value makes a logical statement false?

Comment: are you looking for `which`?

Comment: Note that since R is a vector language, this question is not trivially answerable outside the case you have given - since it's not a statement in boolean logic, but a statement over integer vectors of arbitrary length.  For example, if x and y are unknown, but z=1, then every element of the result is indeed false, but the length of x and y can determine the length of the result.

Comment: @AlexBrown That is an excellent point, and part of the issue I have been dealing with. The atomic elements of Boolean Algebra, and the atomic elements of R are different.

Comment: I think a generic solution must parse the expression into an abstract syntax tree (AST) and evaluate the tree. Then you can "walk" the tree and decide which node with the value FALSE "contributes" to the overall result (in the root node of the AST). Any insider here who can give a hint on how to build and evaluate an AST? `parse`?

Comment: @RYoda That is an excellent idea.

Comment: @Carl I think Hadley described how to parse R code into an AST and walk the tree in his book: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html - the pryr package seems to provide everything you need.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of writing `x==1 & y==1 & z==2` you could define

```
cn <- c(x == 1, y == 1, z == 2)
```

or

```
cn <- c(x, y, z) == c(1, 1, 2)
```

and use `all(cn)`. Then

```
which(!cn)
# [1] 3
```

gives the source(s) of `FALSE`.

In general, no, there is no such function that you are looking for, but for different logical statements a similar approach should work, although it might be too lengthy to pursue.

Considering `(!(x %in% c(1,2,3)) & y==3) | z %in% c(4,5)`, we get `FALSE` if `z %in% c(4,5)` is `FALSE` and  `(!(x %in% c(1,2,3)) & y==3)` is `FALSE` simultaneously. So, if `(!(x %in% c(1,2,3)) & y==3) | z %in% c(4,5)` returns `FALSE`, we are sure about `z` and still need to check `x` and `y`, so that the list of problematic variables can be obtained as follows:

```
if(!((!(x %in% c(1,2,3)) & y==3) | z %in% c(4,5)))
  c("x", "y", "z")[c(x %in% c(1,2,3), !y == 3, TRUE)]
# [1] "x" "y" "z"
```

or

```
a <- !(x %in% c(1,2,3))
b <- y == 3
c <- z %in% c(4,5)
if(!((a & b) | c))
  c("x", "y", "z")[c(!a, !b, TRUE)]
# [1] "x" "y" "z"
```

Comment: Interesting, the example I posted is trivially simple. I wonder if this could be extended to more complex example. Like if I wanted `(x not %in% c(1,2,3) and y==3) | z %in% c(4,5)` could I still create `cn`?

Answer (score 1):

I like @julius's answer but there is also the stopifnot function.

```
x <- 1; y <- 1; z <- 2
stopifnot(x == 1, y == 1, z == 1)
#Error: z == 1 is not TRUE
```

Not that the result is an error if there are any false statements and nothing if they're all true.  It also stops at the first false statement so if you had something like

```
x <- T; y <- F; z <- F
stopifnot(x, y, z)
#Error: y is not TRUE
```

you would not be told that z is FALSE in this case.

So the result isn't a logical or an index but instead is either nothing or an error.  This doesn't seem desirable but it is useful if the reason you're using it is for checking inputs to a function or something similar where you *want* to produce an error on invalid inputs and just keep on moving if everything is fine.  I mention stopifnot because it seems like this *might* be the situation you're in.  I'm not sure.

Here is a silly example where you might use it.  In this case you apparently only want positive numbers as input and reject everything else:

```
doublePositiveNumber <- function(x){
    stopifnot(is.numeric(x), x >= 0)
    return(2*x)
}
```

which results in

```
> doublePositiveNumber("hey")
Error: is.numeric(x) is not TRUE
> doublePositiveNumber(-2)
Error: x >= 0 is not TRUE
> doublePositiveNumber(2)
[1] 4
```

So here you guarantee you get the inputs you want and produce and error message for the user that hopefully tells them what the issue is.